# Dataloader CLI export records modified since process last run date

Tags: data-loader, data-export

**What**

I am trying to use Dataloader CLI to export Contacts created or modified since the process ran the last time.

The process runs properly, but it always retrieves the same records, and I want it to extract only the ones that have been modified (or created) since this process ran the last time.

**Examples**

This is how I run the process:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>process.bat
>   "C:\dataloadercli" contact-extract

This is part of the output message shown when I run the process:

> Rate: 3.600.000 records per hour. Estimated time to complete: 0
>   minutes and 0 seconds.  There are 9 successes and 0 errors. 2015-05-29
>   08:13:14,434 INFO  [contact-extract] progress.NihilistProgressAdapter
>   doneSuccess (NihilistProgressAdapter.java:63) - The operation has
>   fully complet ed.  There were 9 successful extractions and 0 errors.

My process-conf.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>

<bean id="contact-extract"
          class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
          singleton="false">
      <description>Descarga los contactos</description>
        <property name="name" value="contact-extract"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="c:\\salesforce\\logs\\sfdcSoapTrace.log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="xxxxx@xxxx"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="c:\\dataloadercli\\key.txt"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="select ID__c, MobilePhone, Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE ID__c != NULL"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="c:\\dataloadercli\\mappings\\contact-extract-map.sdl"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Contact"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="c:\\dataloadercli\\desdeSalesforce\contact-extract.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.useEuropeanDates" value="true"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.readUTF8" value="true"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true"/>
                <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2005-12-01T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Questions**

Any idea about how can I do this??

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar question. Hopeful that you found the answer!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't.\n

Comment: I found that you can filter using @process.lastRunDate@ in the WHERE clause if you use "dataAccess.type=databaseRead" in the process-conf.xml bean if your data come from a database instead of a CSV file.

Comment: Thank you Victor_JF for the reply! I ended up modifying the file via Windows batch scripts to put the date into the file before the data loader runs. Not very clean, but it works.

Comment: Hi Caleb, what changes did you make to the windows batch file to achieve this ? I've a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic solution for Apex CLI out of the box where you can use the process.lastRunDate from the properties file.  However you can set a date filter like below which will limit the rows returned.  The first example is where you hardcode a set datetime and the second example you can use a datetime function that is part of the SOQL.

1. Example (Pull everythng modified after midnight on August 1, 2015)
   select ID__c, MobilePhone, Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE ID__c != NULL AND LastModifiedDate > 2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z
2. Example: (Pull Everything modified in the past 3 days)
   select ID__c, MobilePhone, Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE ID__c != NULL AND LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@process.lastRunDate@` in the query. An example can be found on [Data Loader Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf), page 34.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Spring Placeholder and SpEL work. While Dataloader allows for use of @process.lastRunDate@ in **SQL** queries, queries against some outside data source for IMPORT into Salesforce,
it does not allow for  @process.lastRunDate@ in **SOQL**, to limit data to be EXTRACTED form salesforce.
However, it is noted in the Dataloader documentation that it is based on SPRING. From Dataloader documentation: *The Data Loader configuration files are based on the Spring Framework, which is an open-source,full-stack Java/J2EE application framework. The Spring Framework allows you to use XML files to configure beans. Each bean represents an instance of an object; the parameters correspond to each object's setter methods.*
See the bean LASTRUN using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and the use of #{} wrapping around ${} below.
${} is placeholder replacement syntax to replace with named property from some property source (in this case a property file)
and #{} is SpEL syntax, allowing for doing SUBSTR on the returned property value.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>

    
  <!--Have not yet found a way to use LAST RUN file on a process by process basis when job is running multiple extracts-->
  <bean id="lastRun" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer " lazy-init="default">
      <property name="location" value="../../LastRun/Export Opportunities_lastRun.properties"/>        
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />          
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />  
      <property name="valueSeparator" value="?" />     
                                                          
  </bean> 
  
  
  <bean id="A-ExportOpportunitiesCsv" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
    <description> *** Export(Extract) Opportunities ***"</description>
    <property name="name" value="Export Opportunities"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
      <!-- Overrides and additions to values provided in config.properties -->
      <map>
        <entry key="process.operation"          value="extract"/>
        <entry key="process.outputError"        value="OpportunitiesERROR.csv"/>
        <entry key="process.outputSuccess"      value="OpportunitiesSUCCESS.csv"/>
        <entry key="dataAccess.type"            value="csvWrite"/>
        <entry key="dataAccess.name"            value="..\..\DATA\Opportunities.csv"/>
        <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8"       value="false"/>
        <entry key="sfdc.entity"                value="Opportunity"/>
        <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="2000"/>
        <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" 
               value="SELECT id, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp
                      FROM Opportunity 
                      WHERE SystemModstamp >= 
    #{ '${process.lastRunDate}'.substring(0,10)+'T00:00:00.000-0400'}
                      and  IsDeleted = FALSE
                     "/>
      </map>
    </property>
   
  </bean>
```